# C# user-defined application settings are not loaded on system startup

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a C# WindowsForms application that uses `Properties.Settings.Default` to store application and user settings. Reading and writing custom user values works correct.

Application is set to automatically run on system startup or user sign on. Here's the problem: when the app starts on system startup it cant load any user-specific settings. They're all set to their default values. When i close the app and restart it - all user settings are back.

After debugging and logging i narrowed down the issue: on normal start application's working directory is set to the directory it was installed into. On system start (or user sign in) working directory is set to `C:\system32` (or similar). That's when user settings are not loaded.

**Is this a proper behavior ? If so, how would i correctly load (or reload) user settings?**

NOTE: My application is deployed with ClickOnce so i can't really control where the settings file is stored. Also, i don't have any issues persisting the settings between the version upgrades.

Comment: I am surprised you got a click-once app to work at system startup at all. Clickonce is highly user specific.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain what would you recommend using instead? Main reason why i went with Clickonce is ease of publishing and updating the app.

Comment: I was in a similar situation as you in the past, in the end I gave up on `Properties.Settings.Default` and instead just created a class that was serializeable with a `XmlSerializer` and stored my config in a subfolder of [`Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx) so settings where shared between all users but i had to manual saving and loading of the config.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I think it's normal to run click-once application on user login (so, on system startup for specific user).

Comment: @Evk "on system startup" has a very specific meaning, that means the program is launched before the user completes the username/password screen. "on user login" is a totally separate category in the windows scheduled tasks world.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain btw, i was able to get the issue sorted by setting registry key to `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Programs) + @"\Published\App.appref-ms";`

Comment: @DanSosedoff post that as an ansewer with details about which key you set, it may be useful to future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution, although i'm not sure how "correct" it is.

In my application when user clicks on "Start on boot" checkbox option, i was writing the following into the registry:

```
string keyname = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run";
RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(keyname, true);
key.SetValue("MyApp", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
```

The issue was resolved when i changed the app path to:

```
var startPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Programs)
  + @"\Published\App.appref-ms";
key.SetValue("MyApp", startPath);
```

I think it has something to do with how ClickOnce apps are typically launched. I start the app using the desktop shortcut, not directly running exe file.